# Function callbacks erros

Tags: pybind11

I have a code in c, with some function callbacks as follows

```
 int (*number) (int i, int j);
```

And then a structure such as follows

```
  typedef struct _name{
        int sal;
        number details;
  }name;
```

I tried to bind this as follows

```
  py::class_<name>(m,"name")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def_readwrite("sal",&name::sal)
      .def_property("details",[](name &self){return self.details;},[](name &self,std::function<int(int,int)> func){self.details=*func.target<name>();});
```

When I tried to do as follows in python

```
 def some_manipulation(int a, int b):
      return a*b;


 name.details=some_manipulation;
```

I am ending segmatation fault core dumped.

Answer (score 0):

pybind11 wraps python function with temporary `std::function` instance when you pass it to C++.

Then `std::function::target()` returns `nullptr`, because stored callable object is NOT a plain function pointer, see  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target